How to fetch data in server component then update it in child client component?
My project needs to watch a MongoDB instance for updates to a leaderboard, and then live-update the page content. I'm using the NextJS v13 App Router, so the database logic is in server components, however I can't figure out how to pass the updates to the child components.
The main page (server component):
export default async function Home() {
    await connectToDatabase();

    let data = await getUsers();
    User.watch().on("change", e => {
        console.log(e);
        // Updating user logic would go here.
    });

    return (
        <Leaderboard users={data}/>
    );
}

async function getUsers(): Promise<UserDAO[]> {
    let query = await User.find({});
    let data: UserDAO[] = [];

    query.forEach(it => {
        data.push({
            uuid: it._id.toString(),
            name: it.name,
            money: it.money,
            online: it.online,
        });
    });

    return data;
}

The child component (client component):
"use client";

export default function Leaderboard(props: Props) {
    var [ users, setUsers ] = useState(props.users.filter(it => !it.vip));

    return (
        <div className="block max-w-full p-4 m-0 border rounded-lg shadow bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">     
            <div className={`grid grid-cols-1 grid-rows-${users.length} gap-16 gap-y-6 grid-flow-row`}>
                {
                    users.sort((a, b) => b.money - a.money).map(user => <LeaderboardEntry key={user.uuid} user={user} place={users.indexOf(user) + 1} />)
                }
            </div>
        </div>     
    );
}

I tried initially to make use of useState or useEffect but as the data fetching takes place on a server component there was an error when I tried to implement it. Calling User.watch().on(...) caused an error with the types used in the schema, which I presume means that kind of fetching can't/is unsafe to execute in a client component. I tried creating a ContextProvider...
"use client";

import { UserDAO } from "@/models/user";
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from "react";

interface UsersContextType {
    users: UserDAO[];   
    setUsers: Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserDAO[]>> 
}

export const UsersContext = createContext<UsersContextType>({
    users: [],
    setUsers: () => { }
});

export default function UserContextProvider({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<UserDAO[]>([]);
    return (
        <UsersContext.Provider value={{ users, setUsers }}>
            {children}
        </UsersContext.Provider>
    );
}

but when I tried to access it (from a server component, which is where the data would need to be updated from). there was this error:
TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.useContext) is not a function


Server components are stateless. That data doesn't "live" in the server component, it is serialized to the client as props. So you would need to make an API call in the client component to update the data. Abstract out the data fetching into an async function, call it in the server component to render, expose it in an API route handler, then use useEffect and fetch to update it client side.

Has pointed @jared your server components won’t update. Maybe you could try sse or websocket and connect the client to those updates

@JaredSmith the data isn't updated by polling an API route, I need it to dynamically update whenever the database watcher receives an event, i.e. User.watch().on("change", e => { /* some logic to update */});

Ended up using a WebSocket server, worked like a charm but took a bit of hacky setup & annoying to have to set up a whole new system for it.
